# android: add Tab bar to all activities in an application

Tags: android

I have to add TabBar to each activities in my application. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [include tag](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-reuse.html) or [viewstub](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-stubs.html) or even [fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html)

Here's how to use `include` to achieve what you want

1. Create layout file that describes your toolbar, e.g. toolbar.xml
2. In each XML layout file you want your toolbar to appear add `include` tag pointing to your toolbar.xml

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    <include android:id="@+id/titleBar" layout="@layout/title_bar" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="48dip" />
    <!-- All the rest of your activity layout below -->
</RelativeLayout>
```